# SQL - Ability to run the query remotely 15 minutes after its last run

Tags: dynamic-sql

I am running below query to check for records created in the last 15 minutes.

```
    SELECT om.OrderMarketRef, o.OrderRef, o.OrderID,s.SecurityName,s.SEDOL,a.AccountID,a.AccountName,c.CompanyID AS BranchCode, n.LogItemMessage + ISNULL ('  User comment: ' + n.UserComment, '')AS AuditMessage, u.UserName, n.LogItemTimeStamp AS AuditTimeStamp, o.TargetConsiderationTrade, o.TargetAmount, o.TargetQuantity, n.ChangeLogRef,o.CreationDate
             FROM Order_LogItem n WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN Orders o WITH (NOLOCK) ON n.MasterOrderRef = o.MasterOrderRef         
INNER JOIN dbo.Account a WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.AccountRef = a.AccountRef 
INNER JOIN dbo.Company c WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.CompanyRef = c.CompanyRef
LEFT JOIN [User] u ON u.UserRef = n.UserRef
LEFT JOIN Orders_Market om WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.OrderMarketRef = om.OrderMarketRef    
INNER JOIN dbo.[Security] s WITH (NOLOCK) ON om.SecurityRef = s.SecurityRef
WHERE n.LogItemMessage LIKE '%Cannot insert duplicate key row in object%' AND  

--     -- Only consider orders created within 30 minutes of each other
o.CreationDate>= DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETDATE())
```

This will call to the SQL server remotely via an automation job. That automation job will run every 15 minutes. However, if there is a connection problem, then the automation job may be delayed. For instance query run at 11:30. Then automation should run 11:45 but has run at 11:55 meaning when it runs at 11:55, it will look at records from 11:40 till 11:55.

The problem with above is I am missing timeframe from 11:30 till 11:40.

What I thought of doing is make the query check its last execution timestamp from SQL server and run 15 minutes onwards from its last execution time on the server so make it more dynamic. At the moment as shown below, I am hard coding 15 mintues from current time stamp

```
o.CreationDate>= DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETDATE())
```

How can I achieve this from witin the SQL script?